# javaScript quicksort not working when entries are >= 10

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I have a table and I want to sort it by one field. However, I need to carry another field, which will provide the needed data for swapping the table entries. It works, but when the field that we sort by has a value 10 (maybe this will be a problem for entries >=10), it interprets 10 as 1, thus sorting results for the dataset 10 8 5 9 to 9 8 5 10.
I can't figure out what's going on! Can you? :)

SOLUTION (by Vache)
The problem is that entries of array to be sorted are strings and not integers! I was collecting the entries of the array with jQuery and .text(). In addition I need to use parseInt() to convert string to an integer.

```
/** 
 * Will swap two table entries 
 * @param a - name of first player
 * @param b - name of second player
 */
function swapEntries(a, b)
{
    var editor = $("#" + a);  //put your ids here
        var viewer = $("#" + b);

    editorContent = editor.clone();
        viewerContent = viewer.clone();

    editor.replaceWith(viewerContent);
        viewer.replaceWith(editorContent);
}

/** 
 * Will swap two array cells
 * @param ar - array
 * @param a - first cell's index
 * @param b - second cell's index
 */
function swap(ar, a, b)
{
    var temp = ar[a];
    ar[a] = ar[b];
    ar[b] = temp;
}

/**
 * Quicksort.
 * @param a - The array to be sorted.
 * @param first - The start of the sequence to be sorted.
 * @param last - The end of the sequence to be sorted.
 * @param names - Array of names.
 */
function quickSort( a, first, last, names ) 
{
    var pivotElement;
    if(first < last)
    {
        pivotElement = pivot(a, first, last, names);
        quickSort(a, first, pivotElement-1, names);
        quickSort(a, pivotElement+1, last, names);
    }
}



/**
 * Find and return the index of pivot element.
 * @param a - The array.
 * @param first - The start of the sequence.
 * @param last - The end of the sequence.
 * @param names - Array of names.
 * @return - the pivot element.
 */
function  pivot( a, first, last) 
{
    var p = first;
    var pivotElement = a[first];

    for(var  i = first+1 ; i <= last ; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] > pivotElement)
        {
            p++;
            swap(a, i, p);
         swapEntries(names[i], names[p]);
         swap(names, i, p);
        }
    }

    swap(a, p, first);
    swapEntries(names[p], names[first]);
    swap(names, p, first);

    return p;
}
```

Comment: Include the code that initializes your arrays. I have a feeling your array to-be-sorted is full of strings instead of integers.

Comment: create a fiddle if u can...

Comment: Is there a particular reason to not use the built-in sort function? Browsers probably already use quicksort or some variant of it, and has the benefit of being a native call instead of a Javascript implementation and should be faster than doing it yourself. You can supply a custom compare function if you need to as well.

Comment: The strings was the problem. I was not aware of any built-in sort. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the arrays, your problem is probably that your numbers are actually strings.

With the way sorting is handled by JavaScript,

```
>>> "10" > "2"
false
>>> 10 > 2
true
```

Also worth noting, as soon as one of your operands is a number a conversion is made to have a number comparison. So,

```
>>> "10" > 2
true
>>> 10 > "2"
true
```